# Handshake failure when call Amazon API Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jax-rs, resteasy, aws-api-gateway

I'm getting a "Handshake failure" when I call Amazon API Gateway over HTTPS.

My code looks like:

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
final Response name = client.target("https://SOME_ID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod")
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HEADER_APIKEY, HEADER_APIKEY_VALUE)
        .post(Entity.json(myEntity));
```

And the error is:

```
13:45:42,602 INFO  [stdout] (Batch Thread - 1) Batch Thread - 1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
13:45:42,603 INFO  [stdout] (Batch Thread - 1) Batch Thread - 1, called close()
13:45:42,603 INFO  [stdout] (Batch Thread - 1) Batch Thread - 1, called closeInternal(true)
13:45:42,627 WARN  [org.jberet] (Batch Thread - 1) JBERET000001: Failed to run batchlet org.jberet.job.model.RefArtifact@77e69caf: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:436)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:195)
```

I did some test writing a native Java code, and works fine. Only if I use Jaxrs doesn't works.

```
    final URL url = new URL("https://SOME_ID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod");
    final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty(HEADER_APIKEY, HEADER_APIKEY_VALUE);
```

My environment is JDK 1.8.0_92 and Wildfly 10.0.0, that uses Resteasy.

How I can fix this error?

(update)
Logs with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose: https://gist.github.com/garcia-jj/9ca7704a690c36be09d4d2e44a4e33a7

Resteasy version: 3.0.14
httpclient version: 4.5
httpcore version: 4.4.1

When I use Resteasy directly, instead of using Jaxrs client, it works fine.

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
    .httpEngine(new URLConnectionEngine()).build();
final Response name = client.target("https://SOME_ID.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod")
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header(HEADER_APIKEY, HEADER_APIKEY_VALUE)
    .post(Entity.json(myEntity));
```

Comment: Sounds like potentially an SNI issue. Can you try diagnosing the issue by turning on SSL debugging? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug

Comment: @LorenzodeLara I shared a gist with the logs. https://gist.github.com/garcia-jj/7a6039613ca2776057125fa65824f941

Comment: Thanks, can you rerun your test with the following flag: -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose

Comment: @LorenzodeLara Looks like the same. Thank you. https://gist.github.com/garcia-jj/9ca7704a690c36be09d4d2e44a4e33a7

Comment: Can you make sure your Apache HttpClient is at least 4.3.2? Based on https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1089 I would've expected the following to appear in your SSL log: server_name, server_name: [host_name: XXXXXXXXXX]

Comment: I'm sorry to long delay. Yes, I'm using httpclient-4.5 (available in Wilfly 10.0.0). I change my code to use resteasy client implementation instead of calling `Client` from jaxrs classes. And it works. The code: `new ResteasyClientBuilder().httpEngine(new URLConnectionEngine()).build()`